# Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, swift, nib

```
2016-06-10 16:16:15.340 SwipePageTest[4625:434547] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Alexk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1A09A104-D0BF-44EA-8FAD-B90A3599FF8C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3213D8DB-6294-43C0-A4F6-AF075812EE3D/SwipePageTest.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewControler0''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087cfd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a573deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087cfcbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001093bfc89 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 499
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001091918d6 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000109192202 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000109192560 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000109192cd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   SwipePageTest                       0x00000001085e4cf4 _TFC13SwipePageTest14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 500
    9   SwipePageTest                       0x00000001085e6422 _TToFC13SwipePageTest14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000109192984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001091d6fae -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 54
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001091d7882 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 462
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001091d79f4 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 126
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001091d8c4d -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 890
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001091d9d0b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000109388503 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001090b2980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010da7dc00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010da7208e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010da71f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010da663c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010da94086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010da947f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086f4c37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086f4ba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001086ea11c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000108ff2f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000108ff7f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    29  SwipePageTest                       0x00000001085e7252 main + 114
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b03792d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**Code:**

```
let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewControler0", bundle: nil)
self.addChildViewController(vc0)
self.scrollVIew.addSubview(vc0.view)
vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)



let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewControler1", bundle: nil)

var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
vc1.view.frame = frame1

self.addChildViewController(vc1)
self.scrollVIew.addSubview(vc1.view)
vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

let vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewControler2", bundle: nil)

var frame2 = vc2.view.frame
frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
vc2.view.frame = frame2

self.addChildViewController(vc2)
self.scrollVIew.addSubview(vc2.view)
vc2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


let vc3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewControler3", bundle: nil)

var frame3 = vc3.view.frame
frame3.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 3
vc3.view.frame = frame3

self.addChildViewController(vc3)
self.scrollVIew.addSubview(vc3.view)
vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Answer (score 5):

Visit the properties of the .xib files in the file inspector ，the property "Target Membership" pitch on the select box ，then your xib file was linked with your target